# How can i set ASPxNavBar groups control

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, devexpress

I have a ASPxNavBar control in my project. It has some NavBarGroup which has contenttemplate.

Hasta Tc Kimlik No:
                                
                                
                                     
                                    
                                        
                                    
                                
                            
                            
                                
                                    Ad:

```
                                </dx:ASPxTextBox>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                Soyad:
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <dx:ASPxTextBox ID="txtHastaSoyad" runat="server" Width="170px">
                                 </dx:ASPxTextBox>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>
                 </ContentTemplate>
            </dx:NavBarGroup>
         ......................
```

I want to get NavBarGroup and set its control's value.

```
            Hasta hasta = new Hasta(Session["hasta_id"].To<int>());
            NavBarGroup hastaGrup = nbDiyalizBildirim.Groups.FindByName("hasta");
            ((ASPxTextBox)hastaGrup.FindControl("txtHastaTCkimlikNo")).Text = hasta.M_TcKimlikNo;
            ((ASPxTextBox)hastaGrup.FindControl("txtHastaAd")).Text = hasta.M_Adi;
            ((ASPxTextBox)hastaGrup.FindControl("txtHastaSoyad")).Text = hasta.M_Soyadi;
```

How can i set their values?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The following code works fine here:

```
protected void ASPxNavBar1_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        ASPxNavBar navBar = sender as ASPxNavBar;
        ASPxTextBox txtBox = navBar.Groups[0].FindControl("txtBox") as ASPxTextBox;
        txtBox.Text = "some test string";
    }
```

Here is the aspx markup:

```
<dx:ASPxNavBar ID="ASPxNavBar1" runat="server" OnPreRender="ASPxNavBar1_PreRender">
    <Groups>
        <dx:NavBarGroup>
            <ContentTemplate>
                <dx:ASPxTextBox ID="txtBox" runat="server"></dx:ASPxTextBox>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </dx:NavBarGroup>
    </Groups>
</dx:ASPxNavBar>
```

Comment: i don't want to set value on prerender. i have a button. when i click it a popup control open. popup control has gridview that has a list. when i choose an item at list i want to set value navbargroup controls.